# copiar columna de datos de SAP a Excel

Tags: excel, script, macros, sap

Buen día
quiero copiar una columna de datos que tengo en SAP y pegarla en mi Excel
como le doy copiar a la COLUMNA1 que ya lo tengo seleccionada y la pego en excel

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtP_INFORM").SetFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtP_INFORM").caretPosition = 3
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell").setCurrentCell -1, "COLUMNA1"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell").firstVisibleRow = 420
**session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell").selectColumn "COLUMNA1" 'selecciono la columna**
```

como le doy copiar a la COLUMNA1 que ya lo tengo seleccionada
y la pego en excel